# Eclipse 4 RCP browser

Tags: browser, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have created an Eclipse 4 RCP application that uses SWT.Browser in some Parts. Inside Eclipse RCP, everything works fine, but after exporting the application, everytime the Parts with browsers are created, the application crashes with this output:

```
(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GtkWidget'

(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot add class private field to invalid type '<invalid>'

(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GtkBuildable'

(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(triglav:30194): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(triglav:30194): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the error messages, but is it possible that the swt fragment is missing in your product e.g. "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86", in your case "org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" or a similar fragment.

Running from eclipse I think the right fragment is chosen automatically, but it is not added to the product automatically.